# Postgres: COALESCE all columns

Tags: postgresql, null, coalesce

I'm dealing with a table that has way too many columns for good design. (Close to 100).  I can't change the schema.

I need to COALESCE each column to be 0 on NULL.  Is there a way to do this without typing out all 100 columns by hand?  (Perhaps using some type of data dictionary or meta information?)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Postgres function to achieve the desired output.

Sample table and data -

```
create table t(id serial, col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int, coln int); 
insert into t values ( 1, 1, 2, null,null,null,1),(1, null, null, null,2,null,6);
```

Following select statement will create dynamic `select` to get all tables with `coalesce()`.

```
SELECT format('select %s from t', string_agg(format('coalesce(%s,0)', column_name), ',')) q
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'public'
    AND table_name = 't'
```

Result:

```
q                                                                                                                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
select coalesce(id,0),coalesce(col1,0),coalesce(col2,0),coalesce(col3,0),coalesce(col4,0),coalesce(col5,0),coalesce(col6,0),coalesce(coln,0) from t 

(1 row(s) affected)
```

You can wrap this into a function

```
 create or replace function get_table_t ()
returns setof t as $$
declare qry text;
begin
    SELECT format('select %s from t', string_agg(format('coalesce(%s,0)', column_name), ','))
    into qry
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'public'
        AND table_name = 't'; 
    return query

    execute qry;
end;$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Usage: `select * from get_table_t()`

Output:

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 coln 
-- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
1  1    2    0    0    0    1    0    
1  0    0    0    2    0    6    0
```